# Firebase-Php-Kreait-4.17-AdminSdk

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-admin

I want to create admin panel for my mobile app, I tried to use Firebase Admin SDK. So, I can manage my Fireabse Realtime Database it is okay. but I need to manage all parts including Firebase Auth. So I need to add authentication with Admin SDK ... How can I start with admin authentication?

[image]

Comment: I mean I need to start Admin session on my web app

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.